# Javascript access host terminal

Tags: javascript, html, terminal

Is it possible to access the host terminal from the web? Some kind of HTML5 magic.

I'd like to build a javascript library around R.

Comment: Do you really think that would be a good idea? Think about it.

Comment: There could be a HTML5 option, like with geolocation etc.

Comment: Browsers try to sandbox themselves from the OS and you want to give them direct access?  Yes, I would like you to be able to do anything to my computer. It is not a smart option, hence why it is not possible. It is like saying to some stranger, here is the key to my house, please do not steal anything or ransack the place.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not.  For security reasons the browser does not allow websites to have access to the host machine except for user authorized actions like downloading a file or giving access to a microphone or webcam.  A user cannot authorize access to the terminal on it's machine.